# trouble in making the if stament work with the math

Tags: objective-c, xcode

hi i am  new in xcode with the if statement for weight

```
int weight;

if (weight <10) { 
([ input.text * @" 100 " Floatvalue); }

if (weight 10-20){ 
([ input.text == 1000 + 50 for each kg more than 10);}

if (weight >20 ){
([ input.text == 1000 + 20 for each kg more than 20);}
```

Comment: Use `else-if` there, to reduce the average number of comparisons made on every run.

Comment: hi i get trouble it doesnt recognize the < or the 10-20 interval to do the calculation and it doesnt do the math for any statement

Comment: You're not setting `weight` to any value, then trying to compare it to other things. Does that make sense? Being "new in Xcode" doesn't mean that you can make up whatever you want. The rest of your code is mostly invalid.  Please look for some tutorials on the web, or get a book, and then come back when you have a less general problem. As is, this requires answerers to either write your code for you, which won't help you, or give you an entire tutorial, which isn't what this site is for.

Comment: sorry if i did something wrong my mac was turn off i wrote what i remember so so next time copy the full code thanks

Comment: @IvanMonsalve Come on man, how are we supposed to help you make corrections to pseudo code?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question (for example, I gathered you want your output as a string), the following might work for you:

```
if (weight < 10) {
    input.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 100 * weight];  // I'm not really sure what you wanted to do here.
}
else if (weight > 20) {
    input.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1000 + 20 * (weight - 20)];
}
else {
    input.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1000 + 50 * (weight - 10)];
}
```